# How do I delete Tumblr's default favicon

Tags: html, tumblr, favicon

In my custom theme, I've just deleted this line:

```
<link rel="icon" href="{Favicon}"/>
```

But tumblr's default favicon kept appearing. I presume it's because it's stored in `image/favicon.ico` path, but I had no way to remove it. Is there any other way to remove it completely?

Comment: empty temp folder and clear browser cache and cookie..

Comment: I did. I tried incognito mode and 3 different browsers.

Comment: Try viewing the source of the document. Do you see a `<link rel="icon" href="whatever">` line there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have deleted the `<link rel="icon" href="whatever"/>` line from your custom theme, the default favicon was loaded.

I don't know about Tumblr, but the solution is not to remove the line that adds the favicon in your custom theme. Try the following instead.

Put this line of code instead of the line that you removed from your custom theme :

```
<link rel="icon" href=""/>
```

You must be able to display your custom favicon (in case there is one) by simply giving the path to it in the `href` attribute. For example, if you had a favicon called `myFavicon.ico` in the root folder, then your `href` attribute will be `href="myFavicon.ico"`.

Hope this helps, and that it *works*.

Comment: The `stylesheet` has nothing to do with the favicon.

Comment: @unor Corrected the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed with Favicons it sometimes takes time to update for some odd reason, you could always make your own and upload it into the root.

Comment: I did. What I wanted to know is how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just remove the favicon on tumblr, you must replace it with another.